# Site is setup statically - how to make it content managable?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-development, themes, theme-options

This is probably quite a basic question, but I have my site setup statically in WordPress, all I am trying to figure out now is how to add a new section to the WordPress backend where all the content of the site can be edited but I can't seem to find the right information, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hey Martin - Welcome to WPSE. Can you explain what you mean by having your site "setup statically"?

Comment: Hi Jonathan. I had a 'normal' site (it's a one page, scrolling one), then I just installed wordpress and split the index up into header, index and footer.php so it's working exactly the same now as before except inside wordpress. What I want to do now is allow an admin to login to the wp backend, click a section on the left-hand pane and for a page to be there with all the settings and content that can be edited on the site, i.e. the site would be dynamic and not all hard-coded in the index.php. Hope that makes sense now?

Comment: Hey Martin! Thank you for the clarification. The scope of what you're trying to accomplish, as J answered below, is beyond what I imagine can be answered in a simple question. What I recommend is a crash course in theme development. This may prove helpful: http://www.yinpress.com/part-5-beginning-a-theme/

Answer (score 3):

Hire a developer or purchase a customizable theme. I don't get the impression that the answer you are looking for can be easily and clearly stated in a brief manner.

You are going to need crash courses in [Custom Post Types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) and [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), which are basically what makes wordpress what it is (which is why your question is much more loaded than you know).

If you want to include the ability to add custom types of data (i.e. audio, files, or custom field types [radio buttons, selection menus, dropdowns, extra text fields, etc]), you are going to have to learn about [Custom Fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) or check out this ***EXTREMELY*** helpful plugin, [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/).

You will ultimately be editing the index.php file (or page.php, category.php, etc), to have them pull and display the exact data that you want to grab. For example, the standard wp-loop will grab 10 (i think) posts from the "Posts" post-type and display them on the page. If you understand how the loop works, then you can convert your site into a "dynamic site" in the sense that you mean. Making the backend customizable is an entirely different ballgame and will require a developer's knowledge.

I hope that this helps!

j

Comment: thanks but I am a web developer so I should be able to figure it out myself, just trying to find the right information, this one looks as if it could be useful: http://buildinternet.com/2010/01/create-custom-option-panels-with-wordpress-2-9/

Comment: @martincarlin87 : the more precise you make your Question, the better people would be able to Answer. No one knows if you are a developer or if you already made a proto-theme. Things like *"split the index up into header, index and footer.php"* belong to the Q itself.